# Node.js and Jest TypeError with supertest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I am trying to run a basic test on a function within my `hosts.js` but am encountering the below error, which I believe is related to `supertest` in my `hosts.test.js` file which is copied at teh end of this post.

```
> shodan-api@0.0.0 test /home/eth3rk1ll/Development/shodan-api
> jest

 FAIL  tests/unit/hosts.test.js
  POST /
    ✕ should save the host if it is valid (4ms)

  ● POST / › should save the host if it is valid

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined

      11 |     const exec = async () => {
      12 |       return await request(server)
    > 13 |         .post('/api/hosts')
         |          ^
      14 |         .send({ hostName: hostName, ipV4Address: ipV4Address });
      15 |     }
      16 | 

      at Test.Object.<anonymous>.Test.serverAddress (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:55:18)
      at new Test (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:36:12)
      at Object.post (node_modules/supertest/index.js:25:14)
      at exec (tests/unit/hosts.test.js:13:10)
      at Object.it (tests/unit/hosts.test.js:23:15)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.458s, estimated 2s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I have searched online for solutions and the most relative are as below in the `app.js` or `index.js` files.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/api', UserRoutes);
module.exports = app;
```

This is my `index.js` file:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const hosts = require('./routes/hosts');
const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`)
);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/shodan-api', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api/hosts', hosts);

module.exports = server;
module.exports = app;
```

I am declaring express and exporting the `app` object as per the solution.

This is not clearing the error however.

Below are my `hosts.test.js` and `hosts.js` files.

What am I missing from this in order to remediate the error?

`/routes/hosts.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const { Host, validate } = require('../models/host');

// Create a new host object
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validate(req.body);
  if(error) return validationError(res, error);

  let host = new Host({
      hostName: req.body.hostName,
      ipV4Address: req.body.ipV4Address
  });

  host = await host.save();
  res.send(host);
});

module.exports = router;
```

`/tests/unit/hosts.test.js`

```
const request = require('supertest');
const {Host} = require('../../models/host');

let server;

describe('POST /', () => {

    let hostName;
    let ipV4Address; 

    const exec = async () => {
      return await request(server)
        .post('/api/hosts')
        .send({ hostName: hostName, ipV4Address: ipV4Address });
    }

    beforeEach(() => {      
      hostName = 'test host';
      ipV4Address = '192.168.0.10';
    })

    it('should save the host if it is valid', async () => {
        await exec();
        const host = await Host.find(validHostDetails);
        expect(host).not.toBeNull();
      });

    //   it('should return the host if it is valid', async () => {
    //     const res = await exec();
    //     expect(res.body).toHaveProperty('_id');
    //     expect(res.body).toHaveProperty('hostName', 'test host');
    //     expect(res.body).toHaveProperty('ipV4Address', '192.168.0.10');
    //   });
});
```

Comment: Hey, it looks like you declare (in your tests) `let server;` and never assign a value to it. The error can point to that, it tries to read `server.address`, but since `server` is `undefined`, you'll get the error that `undefined` doesn't have an `address` property. Not quite sure of the final solution, but you can try removing that declaration, and importing your `server` that's exported in `index.js` (assuming that was your intention by the name)

Comment: That did lead to teh solution. Cannot believe that was what had me! Thanks man